# Simple way of pushing repo to cdn?

Tags: git, hosting, cdn

What's the simplest recipe you're aware of to push a git repo to a CDN?

Many app developers are beginning projects using nothing but static HTML, CSS, and javascript. It's becoming increasingly possible to write complex apps supporting millions of users in this way, so we should expect this trend to grow, and maybe become not uncommon even for production apps.

For these developers, you don't need to configure a server, you don't have more than a few megabytes to serve, so obviously you just want a CDN (read: high-concurrency low-latency server of static files).

I personally have set up a CDN fairly easily, but since all of the above could be automated to a "push to CDN" service, I wonder if one exists or if there's a recipe with just a few steps? In my own experience, there are lots of intermediate steps and things to configure and services to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Clone the repo on your remote server and every time you want to update the code - login to the server and do git pull.
2. set up git hook that whenever you commit to your production branch it will upload your files to the remote server.
3. use this: https://github.com/resmo/git-ftp

Answer (score 0):

[PageCDN](https://pagecdn.com) accepts github repos as origin. You can connect to a github repo in two ways:

1. Connect to a public github repo, and manually sync new files on every release.
2. Connect to a public/private github repo and use your github Personal-Access-Token and webhooks to push new releases to PageCDN.

Then, once this setup is done, you can do more **aggressive optimizations**, including:

1. HTTP/2 Server Push
2. Brotli-11 compression
3. Immutable Caching